# Вопрос по svn

Tags: svn, контроль-версий

Есть сервер с svn репом(/var/spool/svn). На этом же сервере (/home/www/site1) лежит сайт который находится в этом репозитории. Делаю чекаут, правлю исходники, коммит.
Как обновить информацию в /home/www/site1 после коммита?

Answer (score 1):

Другими словами, у вас 2 рабочих копии - одна у разработчика, другая на веб-сервере? `svn up` обновляет рабочую копию до последней ревизии.

Comment: да действительно. Разобрался в своей беде 
во первых у меня в директории сайта лежала не рабочая копия cvn co исправил эту проблему
потом в /var/spool/svn/_proj_/hooks/post-commit.tmpl переименовываем в post-commit и даем права на выполнение. В этом файле после всех комментариев svn update /home/www/site1
Права на site1 выставил 775 для группы и пользователя от которого запущен svn
Теперь при коммите инфа код на рабочем сайте обновляется =)

Answer (score 0):

Если папка с сайтом привязана к репозиторию (что врятли), то можно сделать чекаут. В противном случае - копирование ручками.